# Instantiating a class in C# from a string

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on a windows phone 7 application which uses Silverlight. What I'm looking to do is create a new instance of a class given a string containing the name of the correct class I would like to create. Below is the snipit of code I'm referring to and I am trying to use it to create the new instance. I know from debugging that serviceClass contains the correct string and if I add ".cs" to it, it would now correspond directly to one of the classes I have, so why isn't it being created?

```
WebViewService foundService; //From above
....
....
services.TryGetValue(mode, out foundService); //Find service
if (foundService == null)
   {
            string serviceClass;
            serviceRegistry.TryGetValue(mode, out serviceClass); //Find serviceClass
            if (serviceClass != null) //create new web service if one is found
            {
                try
                {
                    //TODO: This is not working properly, should create an instance of some child class of WebViewService
                     foundService = (WebViewService)System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(serviceClass+".cs"));
                     services.Add(mode, foundService);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //But instead it always ends up here with ArgumentNullExeption
                }
            }
        }
        return foundService;
    }
```

Any help at all or any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string contains [fully qualified type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx) then you can create instance.

Comment: Yup, I just had the wrong type. You can easily find what type your class is, for this example I used typeof(ScanWebViewService).FullName

Answer (score 2):

Try using the full name of the class (namespace included), without the ".cs" part. For example: `YourApp.Services.YourWebViewService`

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType` doesn't take a string with a file name. It takes a class name or a struct name.